# in xcode, trying to add a code to my ipad, says app application failed, error communicating with device. How do I fix it

Tags: ios, kodi

Trying to add Kodi to Ipad.  Followed instuctions to create it in xcode via ios app signer but when I do the final step the end result said it failed, error communicating with device.  Not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else comes across this error, mine was happening when trying to use an In-House Enterprise Distribution cert.  I fixed it by rebooting my iPad.  I actually did a hard reset (power button and home button until reboot), and when the iPad restarted, it was in some kind of re-configuration mode.  It made me choose a language and wifi network as if it were a brand new iPad, but then it started up and it was no different than before.  Weird.

Answer (score 0):

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmmGs.png) First you have to sign up with your apple ID at developer.apple.com (it's free, only paid if you want to submit your app to appstore). Then in Xcode, be sure Xcode is connected to the same apple ID you sign up in developers.apple.com, to check that go to XCode preferences and go to Accounts tab, then while having your ipad connected to your Mac, select your connected iPad in the corner instead of running a simulator. Now go to your iPad settings/general at the below  VPN settings,there are Device Management tap there , it supossed to says your apple id, tap there and tap Trust "yourappleid@example.com". Now you are able to run the app on your ipad.

Comment: I was able to sign up at developer.apple.com and my apple ID is ok in the account setting of xcode.  However my ipad settings don't have a Device Management.  Its an ipad mini.  I tried opeing it through siri but theres nothing there called that.  Also in xcode, couln't quite figure out what you meant by in the corner, select your connected ipad.  The only way I can see the ipad is by selecting the product through the windows tab.  not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Try to search for Profiles instead of Device ManagemenT